# Implementing recaptcha in nuxt2

Tags: javascript, server, nuxt.js, recaptcha

I'm working on a Nuxt.js 2 project, and I'm using the @nuxtjs/recaptcha package to implement Google reCAPTCHA for form validation. I've successfully added reCAPTCHA to my index page, but when I attempt to display it in the right sidebar of the same index page, it's not showing up as expected.

Here's how I've set it up:

I've installed the @nuxtjs/recaptcha package, and it's configured in my nuxt.config.js.

I've added the nuxt-recaptcha component in my index page, and it works fine there.

However, when I try to place the reCAPTCHA widget in the right sidebar section of the same index page, it doesn't render correctly.

Here's a simplified example of my component structure:
`

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <!-- Other sidebar content -->
  <nuxt-recaptcha sitekey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></nuxt-recaptcha>
</div>
```

I've checked that the sitekey is correct, and the reCAPTCHA widget is supposed to appear in the sidebar, but it doesn't.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly integrate @nuxtjs/recaptcha in a Nuxt.js 2 project and display it within a specific section of the page, such as the right sidebar?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First install @nuxtjs/recaptcha

```
yarn add @nuxtjs/recaptcha
```

Create your site key https://www.iqcomputing.com/support/articles/generate-google-recaptcha-v2-keys/
Add this in nuxt.config.js

```
modules: ['@nuxtjs/recaptcha'],
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  recaptcha: {
    siteKey: 'XXXXX',
    version: 2
  }
},
```

In your login page or component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-alert v-model="recaptchaResponseAlert" variant="danger" class="mt-3" dismissible>Please verify that you are a Human.</b-alert>
    <recaptcha
      id="v2-normal"
      @error="onError"
      @success="onSuccess"
      @expired="onExpired"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      recaptchaResponse: false,
      recaptchaResponseAlert: false
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$recaptcha.init()
    this.widgetId = this.$recaptcha.render('v2-normal', {
      sitekey: "XXXXX"
    });
  },

  methods:{
    onSuccess (token) {
      this.recaptchaResponse = true
      this.recaptchaResponseAlert = false
      console.log('Succeeded:', this.recaptchaResponse)
    },
    onError (error) {
      this.recaptchaResponse = false
      this.recaptchaResponseAlert = true
      console.log('Error happened:', error)
    },
    onExpired () {
      this.recaptchaResponse = false
      this.recaptchaResponseAlert = true
      console.log('Expired')
    },
  }
}
</script>
```